# Reading in. file from C++

Tags: c++, file-io

Let's assume that I have the following file:   wow.txt   which reads

4   a   1  c

and what I want to do is I would like to output the following:

d  1    a  3

change the integer to the corresponding alphabet (d is 4th letter, a is 1st letter 
in the alphabet), and alphabet letter to the corresponding integer 
(a is 1st letter in the alphabet, c is the 3rd letter in the alphabet)

I started with the following code in C++.

```
int main()
{
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("wow.txt");
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("sample.txt");

int k, g;
char a, b;

inFile>>k>>a>>g>>b;
outFile<<(char)(k+96)<<(int)a-96<<(char)(g+96)<<(int)b-96

}
inFile.close();

outFile.close();
}
```

but then here, I could only do it because I knew that the text in wow.txt 
goes integer, character, integer, character. 
Also, even if I knew the pattern, if the text in wow.txt is super-long, then 
there's no way I could've solved the problem using the method I used, manually 
typing in each input (Defining k, g as integers, a, b as characters, and 
then doing inFile>>k>>a>>g>>b;)

Also, I didn't know know the pattern, there's no way 
I could've solved it. I was wondering if there's a C++ 
function that reads the input from the given text file and determines its type, so 
that I could attack the this type of problem in the more general case.
I'm very new to C++ programming language (or programming in general), 
so any help about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a tough one. Good luck.

Comment: Look up the concept of "loop", it's likely to be useful once or twice in your programming career.

Comment: try to read the text file one char at a time, and convert it to the right format. (e.g., if char is an integer 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, convert to alpha and vise versa)

Answer (score 2):

The term you're searching for is *parsing*. It is the idea of taking in text and transforming it into something meaningful. Your C++ compiler, for example, does exactly that with your program's code -- it reads in text, parses it into a series of internal representations that it does transforms on, then outputs binary code that, when run, carries out the intent of the code you wrote.

In your case, you want to turn the problem on its head -- instead of telling the input stream what to expect next from the file, you simply extract everything as text, and then figure it out yourself (you let the stream tell you what's there). If you think about it, it's text (or rather, binary data, but close enough) all the way down anyway, even when you're asking for, say, an integer to be read from the stream -- the stream does the integer parsing for you in that case, but it's still just text being parsed.

Here's some example code (untested) to get you started:

```
std::ifstream fin("wow.txt");

// Read everything in (works well for short files; longer
// ones could be read incrementally (streamed), but this
// adds complexity

fin.seekg(0, fin.end);
std::size_t size = fin.tellg();
fin.seekg(0, fin.beg);

std::vector<char> text(size);
fin.read(&size[0], size);
fin.close();

// Now 'tokenize' the text (into words, in this case characters)
enum TokenType { Letter, Number };
struct Token {
    const char* pos;
    std::size_t length;
    TokenType type;
};

std::vector<Token> tokens;
for (const char* pos = &text[0]; pos != &text[0] + text.size(); ++pos) {
    if (*pos >= 'a' && *pos <= 'z') {
        // Letter! (lowercase)
        Token tok = { pos, 1, Letter };
        tokens.push_back(tok);
        // TODO: Validate that the next character is whitespace (or EOF)
    }
    else if (*pos >= '0' && *pos <= '9') {
        Token tok = { pos, 1, Number };
        while (*pos >= '0' && *pos <= '9') {
            ++pos;
            ++tok.length;
        }
        tokens.push_back(tok);
        // TODO: Validate that the next character is whitespace (or EOF)
    }
    else if (*pos == ' ' || *pos == '\t' || *pos == '\r' || *pos == '\n') {
        // Whitespace, skip
        // Note that newlines are normally tracked in order to give
        // the correct line number in error messages
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected character "
                  << *pos
                  << " at position "
                  << (pos - &text[0]) << std::endl;
    }
}

// Now that we have tokens, we can transform them into the desired output
std::ofstream fout("sample.txt");
for (auto it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it) {
    if (it->type == Letter) {
        fout << static_cast<int>(*(it->pos) - 'a') + 1;
    }
    else {
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i != tok.length; ++i) {
            num = num * 10 + (tok.pos[i] - '0');
        }
        // TODO: Make sure number is within bounds
        fout << static_cast<char>(num - 1 + 'a');
    }
    fout << ' ';
}
fout.close();
```